# About answering questions with pasting from other sources when not knowing the answer and have found might-helpful info in the web

Tags: discussion, scope

The title is maybe in need of modification.

The question is this: If I have found a question I'm not in position to answer(because of lack of knowledge), but have found something interesting in the web that I think it might be helpful for the question posted and understandable for those interested, should I just give the link as a comment or should I copy and paste the script that could be helpful as an answer with a reference to the link? Or maybe should I make a comment to someone else reffering the link of the site I have found so that he could post an answer(but I find this rather off limits)

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If all you can contribute is the link, you should post it as a comment under the question. Posting an answer that only contains a link - commonly referred to as a link-only answer - is frowned upon and such an answer will generally get flagged as Not an Answer. (The reason for this is that such answers are very susceptible to [link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_link) and they bring the overall quality of the site down. The goal is to become a repository of answers, not a repository of unreliable links to relevant documents.)

If you want to post an answer, you should study the link and summarize its important points in a way that actually answers the question. If you do not have the time or the ability to do this, you should simply post the link as a comment.

Finally, before posting a link it is a good idea to ensure that the page is archived in the [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/), so that the archived version is there in case the live website moves or goes down. (Don't link directly to the wayback machine, though - it's polite to the website creators to actually direct traffic to their site instead of an archived mirror.)

Comment: +10 (but one will have to do) for the absolutely meta link to link rot. My God, that is brilliant